# GeoServer inserting braces instead of empty text

Tags: geoserver

I'm running GeoServer 2.13.1 with a Postgres database behind it and try to update features through WFS-T. Which works, except when I try to set fields to null or empty texts. In those cases GeoServer writes a pair of braces {} into the database instead.

Why is that? How can I change that?

EDIT:
The columns are of type *character varying* in postgres and of type *string* in geoserver.
The WFS-T request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0">
    <wfs:Update typeName="abc:layername" xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/geo/abc">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:ValueReference>columnA</wfs:ValueReference>
            <wfs:Value />
        </wfs:Property>
        <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
            <fes:ResourceId rid="layername.12345" />
        </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

EDIT 2:
A log extract showing that it is GeoServer who decides on the braces when writing into the DB:

```
2018-09-03 17:57:04 CEST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: UPDATE "layername" SET "columnA" = $1 WHERE ("fid" = $2)
2018-09-03 17:57:04 CEST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '{}', $2 = '12345'
```

Comment: Write one complete example of WFS-T messages that you send.

Comment: we probably need to see the column types of the table too, and any error messages that may appear in the GeoServer log file

Comment: So far I have seen nothing in the error messages.

Comment: If it is your PostGIS turn on the statement logging and capture the UPDATE statement that GeoServer generates. For getting more info from the GeoServer logs turn logging level into GEOTOOLS_DEVEL.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I am seeing this same issue.